# XSLT file not displaying any XML data

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using C# to process an XSLT sheet which uses XML data.

On my XSLT sheet, I am applying a template which goes through the XML data and is suppose to throw out figures based on the parameters passed through to it.

When I run the XSLT sheet and pass parameters to it, there is no output. The html side of the XSLT seems to run just fine.

Here is my XSLT code :

http://pastebin.com/eL9wnRgK

Here is my XML file :

http://pastebin.com/B3eqbd6K

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to process the above, if we exclude my C# classes that I use to process the xslt, even in the inbuilt XSLT debugger of VS it doesn't seem to do anything (no data is output).

I've spent hours going through but can't really find out where i'm going wrong and there isn't any Syntax that is highlighted red or any errors shown. This language is much harder than c#...

Comment: How do you provide the parameters?

Comment: You cannot seriously expect anyone to debug 250 lines of XSLT for you. Work out the problem, post a 20 line code sample.

Comment: Please can you post the C# code you are using? In particular can you show how you are setting the parameters? Thanks!

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick replys, I really appreciate it. Also Tomalak I think I should have pointed out the xslt code that directly displays the XML data, I will do so in future. @Tim C : I am using a C# XMLConduit(i call it that because it does stuff with the XML etc) : http://pastebin.com/WquPR5m4 and the other c# file is ofcourse the aspx page I am displaying it through and the code for that is : http://pastebin.com/BTswhGnC.

Comment: Also I have some doubt on the 2nd C# code (the .aspx page) on lines 25 and 35 because that is the part that is setting the parameters it seems and I think it's not setup right now that I look at it again. The XMLDataConduit doesn't seem to be at fault here.

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the parameters, and with the desired values. To help troubleshoot, you can hard-code default values for your parameters `<xsl:param name="SearchType" select="'Start'"/>` and verify that you get expected output.

Comment: You have guessed right, I tried that hardcode for the SearchType and would do you know it displays data. So my problem is somewhere along the lines the SearchType parameter is not getting passed to the XSLT and my gut feeling is it's still the C#. I need to create a parameter which the xslt sheet can use. I know the logic, but now I needa figure out how to implement it :(

Comment: Where's your code where you call your xmlConduit's `AddParameter()` method? Have you verified that you're passing it the right parameter names and values? Have you tried hardcoding the values in your C# code to see if that works?

Comment: In regards to your question above, in your comment not the answer. You've seen the XMlConduit class (pastebin.com/vAEqbbYd) and the place where I call the method is in the aspx page (pastebin.com/9ME5JUqW) - Line 35. I understand the values being passed to the function in the XMLDataConduit. I just don't understand how from the DataConduit it gets passed into the XSLT and I'm guessing this is why it's not getting passed. @JLRishe

Comment: I did some debugging and the aspx page where I call the AddParameter() method seems to be passing the string I type into the text box just fine. I also changed some stuff http://pastebin.com/ZrwDRg91 in there (just the name of the filter I guess). In regards to the XMLDataConduit where all the xslt magic happens, it's getting passed to the function and up until line 102 it's being taken over as a param value. I just don't get what happens after that. (I feel like i'm so close....) It's 4:33am I might sleep soon, but I shall read all responses first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT was in need of some serious cleanup. Remember to keep in mind the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). By avoiding the use of repeated parts, I was able to reduce the length of your XSLT by more than 100 lines. Once you figure out how to pass the parameter values correctly, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!--Search parameter to store the search string entered-->
  <xsl:param name="SearchRecipe" />
  <!--Search type parameter to store the type of search selected-->
  <xsl:param name="SearchType" select="'Start'" />
  <xsl:param name ="IsVegetarian" />

  <!--First part of code to capture values from user and then store them 
        in the variables above-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

      <head>
        <!--Sets Title of Page (within our Master template)-->
        <a>
          <title>Recipe Headquarters</title>
        </a>
        <!--Reference to the stylesheet we are using-->
        <link href="Cafesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <form  id="banner" name="content" method="get" action="Commercial.aspx">
          <h1 >Recipe Book</h1>
          <div id="content">
            <p>
              <label id="h2" for="txtFilter">Search Recipe Book </label>

              <input type="text" name="txtFilter" 
                     id="txtFilter" value="{$SearchRecipe}"/>

              <!--Creates a simple submit button-->
              <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" 
                     id="btnSearch" value="Submit" />
              <br />
              <br />


              <!--Label of text for our set of radio buttons-->
              <label for="rdoSearchType">Select a Search Type  </label>

              <!--Behold, the radio buttons themselves-->
              <xsl:call-template name="SearchTypeRadio">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'Start'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Starts with'" />
              </xsl:call-template>
              <xsl:call-template name="SearchTypeRadio">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'Contains'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Contains'" />
              </xsl:call-template>
              <xsl:call-template name="SearchTypeRadio">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'RecipeType'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Recipe Type'" />
              </xsl:call-template>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />

              <!--Applys the template from the second part-->
              <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="CafeRecipes[$SearchType = 'Start' or 
                                    $SearchType = 'Contains' or
                                    $SearchType = 'RecipeType']" />

            </p>
            <!--End our of Search input text box and the Type of search 
                   we want to do Div-->
          </div>

          <!--Our self closing footer div, yayyyy. Single line madness-->
          <h1>Made by Jagga ^_^</h1>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SearchTypeRadio">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <input type="radio" name="rdoSearchType" value="{$value}">
      <xsl:if test="$SearchType = $value">
        <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </input>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--This will be the second part of the xsl code to manipulate the data 
          based on our chosen values from above-->
  <!--Declares new xsl template-->
  <xsl:template match="CafeRecipes">
    <!--Creates a small table to display the data output produced-->
    <table id="content" border="5">
      <tr>
        <th>Recipe #</th>
        <th>Recipe Name</th>
        <th>Ingredients Required</th>
        <th>Instructions</th>
        <th>Recipe Type</th>
        <th>Vegetarian?</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:variable name="matchedRecipes"
         select="ARecipe[
               ($SearchType = 'Start' and starts-with(ItemName, $SearchRecipe)) or
               ($SearchType = 'Contains' and contains(ItemName, $SearchRecipe)) or
               ($SearchType = 'RecipeType' and 
                            contains(RecipeInfo/RecipeType, $SearchRecipe))
                          ]" />

      <xsl:if test="$SearchType = 'Start' or $SearchType = 'Contains'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$matchedRecipes">
          <xsl:sort select="RecipeInfo/RecipeType" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$SearchType = 'RecipeType'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$matchedRecipes">
          <xsl:sort select="ItemName" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ARecipe">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)] | RecipeInfo/*" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ARecipe/* | ARecipe/*/*">
    <td width="300">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="content" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Vegetarian[. = 'Yes']" mode="content">
        YesThisWorks and it's vegetarian
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Vegetarian[. = 'No']" mode="content">
    YesThisWorks and it's NOT vegetarian
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only call to `AddParameter()` I see in your ASPX code is `MyXMLConduit.AddParameter("TheFilter", AFilter);`.  Since the name of your parameter in the XSLT is "SearchRecipe", you need to use that as the parameter name, not "TheFilter". You also need to get the value of the `rdoSearchType` query parameter and add that as one of the XSLT's parameters.

```
string searchType = Request["rdoSearchType"];
if(searchType != null)
{
    MyXMLConduit.AddParameter("SearchType", searchType);
}
```

Comment: Hey there @JLRishe : I really appreciate your response and sorting my code out. I have been messing about the XSLT myself and have not yet applied the code to be shortened. I definetly will however at the moment i'm just trying to get the value to pass through to the xslt from my c#. So far my XSLT looks like such :  [ http://pastebin.com/NvnPFy0b ] .... It does work when as suggested above I hardcode values but what I really need to do is get the values from the c# classes to pass into the xslt sheet.

Comment: @Jagga Thank you.  Added some suggestions about the C# code to my answer.

Comment: I see now, the reason why the parameter (just the 1 I added) was failing simply because that's the name we pass to the xslt and because it's not what we are using in the xslt it wasn't working. I did as you have asked and now it's working as expected. I put in V, it shows all the name of the recipes with V in it etc. It works fine now. I think now I'll be able to sleep :p, Thank you very much @JLRishe and all others who put in their input!

Comment: @Jagga Glad to help, and please do consider using the cleaner XSLT that I provided above.

Comment: @Jagga By trying to fix bugs in your XSLT before cleaning it up, your are revealing your inexperience as a software engineer. It is ALWAYS best to clean up your code first, because the bugs will then be much easier to find; whereas fixing bugs in messy code makes it messier and harder to clean up later.